# Toggling the visibility of React components

Tags: reactjs

The Dropdown does not render when I click the button. I followed an example, but apparently missing something. Knowing the "why" is most important. Also I'd like to make the ToggleVisibility able to handle any component.

```
function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <ToggleVisibility Basicexample={MyDropdown} /> 
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

function Header() {
  // const style = { color: "red", fontSize: "48px", textTransform: "uppercase" };
  const style = {};

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <h1 style={style}>Goals</h1>
    </header>
  );
}


function Footer() {
 
  return (
    <footer className="footer">
     
    </footer>
  );

}
function ToggleVisibility ({basicexample:MyDropdown }) {

  // React state to manage visibility
  const [show, setShow] = useState();

  // function to toggle the boolean value
  function toggleShow() {
    setShow(!show);
  }
  var buttonText = show ? "Hide Component" : "Show Component";

  return (
    <div className="component-container">
      
      <button onClick={toggleShow}>{buttonText}</button>
      {show && MyDropdown}
    </div>
  );
}
function MyDropdown() {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Comment: First things first: casing matters. Secondly you're not actually _rendering_ the component you receive. _"I'd like to make the ToggleVisibility able to handle any component"_ - it already deals the same way with whatever props it's passed.

Comment: If you're toggling you need to set the hook with callback: `setShow(show => !show)` --  And for good measure set your initial state: `const [show, setShow] = useState(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused the props name and the component name in the `ToggleVisibility` method. I would recommend to check how we pass components as props [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).

For this situation, the working code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ToggleVisibility basicexample={<MyDropdown/>} /> 
    </div>
  );
}

function ToggleVisibility ({ basicexample }) {

  // React state to manage visibility
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  // function to toggle the boolean value
  function toggleShow() {
    setShow(show=>!show);
  }
  var buttonText = show ? "Hide Component" : "Show Component";

  return (
    <div className="component-container">
      <button onClick={toggleShow}>{buttonText}</button>
      {show && basicexample}
    </div>
  );
}
function MyDropdown() {
  return (
    <div>"here is a dropdown"</div>
  );
}
```

You can play with the code [here](https://playcode.io/1608671).